# Sublime Text 3 shows "No Build System" on the status bar when I try to compile my C++ code. Why?

Tags: c++, sublimetext3

It shows this error when I try to build it. It has been happening only after I entered the following code in my custom build system file:

It only happens after entering the "Run in CMD" portion of the code

```
{
"shell_cmd": "g++ \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\"",
"file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
"working_dir": "${file_path}",
"selector": "source.c, source.c++",

"variants":
 [
    {
        "name": "Run",
        "shell_cmd": "g++ \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\" && \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\""
    }
    {
        "name": "Run in CMD",
        "shell_cmd": "start \"$file_base_name\" call $file_base_name"
    }
 ]
}
```

The use of the program is to add a variant in which it opens the compiled program in CMD and not the integrated terminal in Sublime Text 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ultimate cause of the `No build system` message being displayed is that Sublime doesn't know what build system it should be applying when you try to run the build.

This can happen when you have the build set to `Automatic` but the current file is of a type that Sublime can't determine the build system for, but it can also happen when the build file that it would use (either through `Automatic` or by being explicitly told) is broken in some manner.

In your case, this is the reason; there is a `,` missing between the two variants on line 12 of your `sublime-build` file. Thus the file is not valid JSON, the build file is treated as if it doesn't exist, and you get the message about there being no build system.

Adding in a comma should fix your problem:

```
{
"shell_cmd": "g++ \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\"",
"file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
"working_dir": "${file_path}",
"selector": "source.c, source.c++",

"variants":
 [
    {
        "name": "Run",
        "shell_cmd": "g++ \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\" && \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\""
    }
// These two variants are part of a list; they need to be separated
// with a comma
    {
        "name": "Run in CMD",
        "shell_cmd": "start \"$file_base_name\" call $file_base_name"
    }
 ]
}
```

Comment: There is a comma on that line

Comment: There isn't, the two variant objects in the variant key are just two adjacent objects, but they're part of the `variants` list. I edited the question to outline the error location. The line number I mentioned was inaccurate; when I pasted it into the linter it reformatted it a bit. Sorry about that.